# How to create a password protected DB in SQLiteStudio

Tags: sqlitestudio

Does anyone know how to create a password protected file in SQLiteStudio 3.1 ?
When I try to make a DB with type SQLCypher, trying to follow the steps in the youtube guidance, I allways end up with a file I can connect to, even without a password.
Can't find any usefull manual for this.....

Answer (score 2):

When you create database, pick SQLCipher plugin, enter password. Newly created database should appear on the list of databases. Now just double click on it and it should open with no issues.

Unless you mean you cannot open it from different application?

Comment: Ok, seems easy enough. Thanks

Comment: yes. actually I just want to create a password for my database and save it as a `.db` file so I can fill it in `DB Browser for sqlite`.